How to search in a pdf or text file by a regex pattern and output locations of matches?
Is there a pdf viewer that allows me to search its text by a regex expression?
In case that I haven't found one, I am thinking about extracting the text and layout from a pdf file by
less my.pdf > mytextfile

or pdftotext -layout. In the text file, pages are separated by form-feed character (Ctrl-L), and lines are separated by line-feed character.
I was wondering how to find all the matches to a given pattern in the text file, and output their locations (page numbers and line numbers in each page)?

I searched for "PDF grep" and the first hit was https://pdfgrep.org/ which looks like it might be exactly what you need. It is installable on Ubuntu with
apt install pdfgrep

And on Arch with
pacman -S pdfgrep

You can use it like grep and give it a pdf file as input. for example:
$ pdfgrep 'glob[au]l' /usr/share/emacs/29.3/etc/refcards/refcard.pdf
Shells                                                          enable or disable input method             C-\                   Making global key bindings in Emacs Lisp (example):
execute a shell command                       M-!                                                                                (global-set-key (kbd "C-c g") ’search-forward)
execute a shell command asynchronously        M-&                                                                                (global-set-key (kbd "M-#") ’query-replace-regexp)
add global abbrev                             C-x a g
add global expansion for this abbrev          C-x a i g                                                                          tively. Type C-h f interactive RET for more details.

And yes, it supports the -n option to include page numbers (from man pdfgrep):

-n, --page-number[=TYPE]
Prefix each match with the number of the page where it was found.
The optional argument TYPE controls how page numbers are determined. If present, it can be one of the following:
index   The index of the page in the PDF, starting at 1 for the first
page. This is the default.
label   The PDF page label. This can be an arbitrary string per page,
set by the PDF creator (e.g. roman numerals for the first few
pages).

